# Scroll to panel after postback C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

How do i scroll to a panel within an updatepanel after i load the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the jQuery ScrollTo plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [jQuery ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) to achieve this.

```
$.scrollTo($('#myPanel'));
```

Here's a [direct link](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to the plugin demo page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we scroll the page to somewhere by appending its name to the url. Here is an example:

```
//test.aspx
<div id="myDiv" name="theDIV">
   I'm in the bottom of the page
</div>
```

At the beginning you visit this page you will see a normal page. But instead in you visit `test.aspx#theDIV` the browser will scroll to the bottom of the page(scroll to the div).

Comment: This is not an option for me. Im loading all the data when the user clicks a submit bottom. But thanks enyway:)

Comment: @Profeten: You can easily redirect the page after clicking the button.

Comment: ye but then i wont be able to use Ajax

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing

```
$("#divGetListforUser .btn").click(function() {
            isClicked = true;
        });
 function scrollTo() {
        if (isClicked) {
            $.scrollTo($("#main .header"), { duration: 1000 });
            isClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

and form codebehind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "scrollToKey", "scrollTo()", true);
```

Comment: Curious - why did you remove the accepted answer from my answer? You're still using the scrollTo plugin for the solution.

Comment: @ geoff Because its not really the full answer to the question